# Is this code first database design is good c#?

Tags: c#, sql, database, entity-framework, code-first

I am working on an Online Interview Reservation project using EntityFramework 6 code first. In this project candidate can book interview only from any country. I have to manage Countries, Cities, Dates and TimeSlots and give control to Admin so he/she can insert values according to availability for interview.

So for this i decided the following Database schema (*this database schema is only for managing the interview slots in each country*)

**Country**   [*has one to many relationship with City*]

```
Id
Name
Code
```

**City**      [*has one to many relationship with Date*]

```
Id
Name
CountryId
```

**Date** [*has one to many relationship with TimeSlot*]

```
Id
Date
Booked
CityId
```

**TimeSlot**

```
Id
Start
End
Duration
Booked
DateId
```

For managing the *available* and *booked* Interview Time slots in each country i have decided to create the above tables (in bold) and properties (in code block). I have also mention the relationship between tables.

I am not good in database design so i just want that you guys please review this and let me know where i can do better that this ??

Comment: This isn't C#-related without seeing your model class. It's about basic database design.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. I personally prefer to give PK's unique names based on their table, e.g. CountryId rather than Id - makes reading FK's much easier.
2. Date is fairly poor name for a table - perhaps BookingDate or even just Booking is better? Same for TimeSlot, maybe BookingTimeSlop?
3. Start and End again are poor names, maybe StartTime or StartOfBooking... same for End.
4. Duration - is that the difference between End and Start... why do you need to store that value?

You're tables do have decent ref. integrity so well done. Good luck!

Comment: thanks for your opinions its really very valuable for me

Answer (score 0):

In addition to robnick's excellent suggestions, consider the following:

1. Date doesn't seem to do much, consider merging it with TimeSlot. Duplicating the date information opens up the possibility of dates being out of sync between Date and TimeSlot.
2. There is no way to tell who has booked a TimeSlot. It's almost guaranteed you'll need a PersonID or something in TimeSlot.
3. With this design you can't book a TimeSlot that isn't already created. This becomes a maintenance burden. Consider removing the Booked property and only creating an entity instance once a TimeSlot has been booked. It will probably be easier to configure the available time slots in a config or using a different entity model.

Answer (score 0):

General rule in naming fields... If it sounds too common like 'Name', 'Date', 'ID', etc. then you better add something to make it like fldName and such. Reserved names are troublesome since a lot of components make use of it. Other than the field names, they look pretty good to me.